# Prevent Nginx to remove port number

Tags: nginx, virtualbox, vagrant

Well, I'm really confused. I have a web server running nginx inside a virtual machine. I'm fowarding the port 8082 from the host machine to the port 80 in the virtual machine. In fact, going to `exampledomain.dev:8082` works as expected showing the web page.

The problem happens when I type a url like this `exampledomain.dev:8082/subdirectory`

The browser redirect me to `exampledomain.dev/subdirectory` without the port number, so nothing works. But if I add a trailing backslash in the url like this `exampledomain.dev:8082/subdirectory/` it works properly.

My question is, how can I point `exampledomain.dev:8082/subdirectory` and `exampledomain.dev:8082/subdirectory/` to the same place and how I prevent nginx from removing the port number?

If is important, this is my actual nginx configuration inside the virtual machine:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name exampledomain.dev;
    root /srv/www/exampledomain;
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;

    location /subdirectory {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /subdirectory/index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest fix is to change your rewrite to

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ http://exampledomain.dev:8082/$1/ permanent;
```